# Rails - bundle install fails on libv8, Python conflict

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails

When running "bundle install" for my project, I am getting the following error:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Using rake (0.9.2.2)
Using i18n (0.6.0)
Using multi_json (1.1.0)
Using activesupport (3.2.1)
Using builder (3.0.0)
Using activemodel (3.2.1)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using journey (1.0.3)
Using rack (1.4.1)
Using rack-cache (1.1)
Using rack-test (0.6.1)
Using hike (1.2.1)
Using tilt (1.3.3)
Using sprockets (2.1.2)
Using actionpack (3.2.1)
Using mime-types (1.17.2)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.10)
Using mail (2.4.1)
Using actionmailer (3.2.1)
Using arel (3.0.2)
Using tzinfo (0.3.31)
Using activerecord (3.2.1)
Using activeresource (3.2.1)
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
Using bundler (1.1.3)
Using coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
Using execjs (1.3.0)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2)
Using json (1.6.5)
Using rdoc (3.12)
Using thor (0.14.6)
Using railties (3.2.1)
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
Installing libv8 (3.3.10.4) with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
.


    C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby
Checking for Python...Unable to build libv8: Python 3.x is unsupported by V8!
```

Gem files will remain installed in C

```
:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.3
.10.4 for inspection.
```

Results logged to

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.3.10.4/ext/libv8/g
em_make.out
```

An error occured while installing libv8 (3.3.10.4), and Bundler cannot continue.

Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.3.10.4'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: What result do you get from trying `gem install libv8 -v '3.3.10.4'`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need V8 in your project? If you're compiling coffee script installing node and NPM is typically easier and faster.